# How to run tmux in detached mode (-d) without getting cluttered output

Tags: output, tmux, ansi-escape, detach

When I run the ffuf (which has live status updates) tool in tmux detached mode, the output is not the same as if I attach to an tmux session and run then the ffuf tool.

After running: `tmux new -d 'ffuf -u https://10.10.10.160:10000/FUZZ'` I get the follownig cluttered output:
[image]

So normally the Progress: [8/100001] appears but then gets replaced with the new progress e.g. [49/100001] so the user know how much fuzzing has already be done. So when running without the -d flag tmux workes correctly in the sense that one only sees one line of proress instead of many.

My endgoal is to run several tmux sessions with different ffuf targets.
So: Is there flag how to run tmux -d but with the same display options as when you run it in not-detached mode? (My assumtion is that tmux shows the cluttered output because it ignores ANSI control chars, which might make sense for other use-cases when starting detached tmux-sessions from a script.)

Answer (score 0):

Posted this as an issue on github:
https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2379

This answer from nicm worked:
This program does not adapt its output to the terminal width. When you create a session with -d you will get the default 80x24 size, and it is attempting to print around 100 characters, so it will wrap.

**Try adding -x 200 to new-session.**